# How to chain functions with a completion handler in Swift?

Tags: swift, chaining, completionhandler

I am chaining some functions together and I can't figure out how to call a completion handler with a return value once all the functions are done running.

```
func getAirQuality(completion: (aqi: Int?) -> Void) {
    callAPI()
}

private func callAPI() {
    // ... get data
    self.parseDataForAQI(data: data)
}

private func parseDataForAQI(data: Data) {
    let aqi = aqi
    // Send aqi up to completion handler in getAirQuality
}
```

So that when everything is said and done I can just do something like this:

```
getAirQuality(completion: { aqi -> Void in {
    // Do something with aqi
})
```

Comment: you have to call completion(aqi: Int?) inside your getAirQuality

Comment: Save the completion somewhere the last function can see it, and call it when that function finishes.

Comment: If you don't mind using 3rd party libraries, [PromiseKit](https://github.com/mxcl/PromiseKit) makes chaining async function calls way easier than having to use completion handlers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My first assumption is that your first 3 functions are part of a class.  If so, one approach is to save the completion handler as an instance variable.

```
class AirQualityProvider {
    var aBlock: ((Int?) -> Void)?

    func getAirQuality(completion: @escaping (Int?) -> Void) {
        aBlock = completion
        callAPI()
    }

    private func callAPI() {
        let data = Data()
        parseDataForAQI(data: data)
    }

    private func parseDataForAQI(data: Data) {
        let aqi = 1
        if let completion = aBlock {
            completion(aqi)
        }
    }
}
```

Here's an example of a caller as written in a playground.

```
let aqp = AirQualityProvider()
aqp.getAirQuality { (value) in
    if let value = value {
        print("Value = \(value)")
    }
}
```